# Paginate the UnorderedSet in near_sdk_rust

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to paginate the [UnorderedSet](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.UnorderedSet.html), can it be done, what collections I have to use for it?

Here is my code:

```
user_products_map: TreeMap<u128, UnorderedSet<u128>>

pub fn get_products_of_user_id(&self, user_id: u128) -> Vec<u128> {
        let products_set_option = self.user_products_map.get(&user_id);
        match products_set_option {
            Some(products_set) => products_set.to_vec(),
            None => {
                panic!("No products for user");
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to paginate like:

```
pub fn get_products_of_user_id(&self, start:u128, end:u128, user_id: u128) -> Vec<u128> {
            let products_set_option = self.user_products_map.get(&user_id);
            match products_set_option {
                Some(products_set) => products_set[start, end].to_vec(),
                None => {
                    panic!("No products for user");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnorderedSet` has [`iter()` method](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.UnorderedSet.html#method.iter), so you can use standard Rust Iterator methods like [`skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) and [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take)

```
products_set.iter().skip(start).take(end).collect()
```